# "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface or struct" error on public static string MyFunc(). What's an alternative to "string"?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, static-methods

I'm getting an error when I attempt to use the following static function.

Error:

> Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct

Function (and class):

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        // Some other static methods that use Classes, delegates, enums, interfaces, or structs

        public static string MyFunc(string myVar){
            string myText = myVar;
            //Do some stuff with myText and myVar
            return myText;
        }
    } 
}
```

This is causing the compiler to angrily (in red) underline the string part of `public static string`.

So, I assume this means `string` is not a class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct.

**What can I use instead of `string` to return a string or string-like object?** There doesn't appear to be a `String` (capital S) class in C#.

**Edit**: Bracket mis-match with some commented code - the above code works correctly, my actual mis-matched code didn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to put the method definition into a class/struct definition. Method definitions can't appear outside those.

Comment: And I'm quite sure it isn't, at least I didn't encounter this particular compiler error with any other cause. Check your braces, that could be a reason as well.

Answer (score 4):

There is a capital S String in C#/.Net - [`System.String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). But that is not your problem. @Femaref got it right - this error is indicating that your method is not part of a class.

C# does not support standalone functions, like C++ does. All methods have to be declared within the body of a class, interface or struct definition.

Comment: quite right. Didn't see the bracket mis-match until it was explained a little better. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when getting re-acquainted with P-Invoke. [Femaref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4824197/3543437) had it right. Here's some sample code for quick visualization purposes:

Working Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Broken Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```