# Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, delegates

I'm trying to get this code out for display but its giving me this error. Is anyone able to help?
Hints and suggestions will be good enough as long as I know where I went wrong.

```
public ObservableCollection<PData> Data = new ObservableCollection<PData>()  
        {

                new PData() { title = "slice #1", value = 30 },  
                new PData() { title = "slice #2", value = 60 },  
                new PData() { title = "slice #3", value = 40 },  
                new PData() { title = "slice #4", value = 10 },

        };

            private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
            {  
                pie1.DataSource = Data;  
            }  


    public class PData  
    {  
        public string title { get; set; }  
        public double value { get; set; }  
    }
```

Comment: Your method is not enclosed in a class. Unless there's more code you are not showing.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824194/expected-class-delegate-enum-interface-or-struct-error-on-public-static-str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error typically means that you have the wrong number of brackets `{` or `}` somewhere in your code, or that (part of?) your code is not within a class.

In your case (if that is indeed all your code), the stuff following:

```
public ObservableCollection<PData> Data (...)
```

is not within a `class { ... }` scope.

If you have more code than shown, and it *is* within a class, look for a class or method definition that has too many close brackets `}`, which could be interpreted as "*the end of a class*".

Simple ex:

```
class Stuff{

    public void DoStuff(){
        ...
    }
    } // accidental extra bracket ends the class Stuff too early

    // Error will show here, since this appears to be outside the class:
    public void DoSomethingElse(){

    }

} // The inteded end of Stuff to be
```

Comment: Yea, I was missing the class. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NameList : ObservableCollection<PersonName>
{
    public NameList() : base()
    {
        Add(new PersonName("Willa", "Cather"));
        Add(new PersonName("Isak", "Dinesen"));
        Add(new PersonName("Victor", "Hugo"));
        Add(new PersonName("Jules", "Verne"));
    }
  }

  public class PersonName
  {
      private string firstName;
      private string lastName;

      public PersonName(string first, string last)
      {
          this.firstName = first;
          this.lastName = last;
      }

      public string FirstName
      {
          get { return firstName; }
          set { firstName = value; }
      }

      public string LastName
      {
          get { return lastName; }
          set { lastName = value; }
      }
  }
```